# ffmpeg how to add pcm codec tag to output

Tags: python, audio, ffmpeg, pcm

In Python script I want to convert bytes from ogg to wav without coping any data on hard disk. I do it in such a way:

```py
args = (
        ffmpeg
        .input('pipe:')
        .output('pipe:', format='s16le', acodec='pcm_s16le')
        .get_args()
       )
p = subprocess.Popen(['ffmpeg'] + args, stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
wav = p.communicate(input=bindata)[0]
```

it works, but produce result different from what `ffmpeg -i sample.ogg sample.wav` does. The difference can be found in ffmpeg's otput in Metadata section:

**ffmpeg -i sample.ogg sample.wav**

```
Metadata:
    ...
    Stream #0:0: Audio: pcm_s16le ([1][0][0][0] / 0x0001), 48000 Hz, mono, s16, 768 kb/s
    ...
```

**Python**

```
Metadata:
    ...
    Stream #0:0: Audio: pcm_s16le, 48000 Hz, mono, s16, 768 kb/s
    ...
```

So, I wonder, how to add this `([1][0][0][0] / 0x0001)` tag to Python variant

Comment: I'm not sure but I think `pipe` can send only audio/video data but not meta data.

Comment: BTW: `pipe` can use some file on disk to comunicate between processes.

Comment: The meaning of both is identical. Any specific reason you need `0x0001`?

Comment: `format='s16le'` generates a raw bitstream which cannot carry a codec tag or any other metadata. Change it to `wav`. Since you're piping the output, the result won't be completely identical.

Comment: for 3rd party software @Lukasz